# Combining Small with a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 sheets; 1 with a large dataset consisting of a non unique identifier and a date
e.g.

```
xx - 01/12/2012
xx - 05/12/2012
xx - 02/11/2012
yy - 02/04/2012
yy - 25/05/2012
zz - 06/03/2013
```

The second sheet has a sample of the identifiers and I need to lookup the earliest date from the main dataset.

If i use a normal `VLOOKUP` it returns the first item in the list for each id.

I can use `Small` to get the earliest date but there is no link to the id.

**Q** How do I combine these to get the earliest date for each id?

**NB** I realise I could just do a second sort on the main table by date after id since the `VLOOKUP` would return the first value but I'm interested in a way to combine these formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an "array formula" like this

`=MIN(IF(A2:A7="xx",B2:B7))`

which needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If there are no "xx" values the result is zero, if you use SMALL instead of MIN, i.e.

`=SMALL(IF(A2:A7="xx",B2:B7),1)`

....then you'll get an error [#NUM!] if there are no "xx" values...

Comment: Very nice! I was trying array formulas with `IFs` and `VLOOKUPs` and getting nowhere.